# Sort html from a sort order populated in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort a html list by a distance, I **do not** want to put distance property in my markup. What I do is that I render the store list html, in js I create a array where I keep the store and distance.

```
locations = [];
locations.push({
    'store': stores[i],
    'cordinate': Math.random()
});
```

I sort that with this

```
locations.sort(dynamicSort('cordinate'));

function dynamicSort(property) {
  var sortOrder = 1;

  return function(a, b) {
    var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
    return result * sortOrder;
  }
}
```

Here is where I get stuck, how can I sort my html using this array? The key here is that I don't want to clutter my html with setting the cordinate there.

[My fiddle is right here](https://jsfiddle.net/wbcj026x/)

**EDIT**
The question was about sorting the output html with the sort order populated in a array. There for I removed the html and other js that I only used because of being lazy to populate markup.

Comment: @hindmost it's not relevant to se html markup for this. But ok.

Comment: Handlebars templates you using are quite relevant to your question.

Comment: you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/znttxbwm/ ?

Comment: store the html element in the 'locations' object, then you can get refferance t o it

Comment: @AdiDarachi I do got a Id in the id that has a reference to the actual html element, but question is how do I do that?

Comment: @hindmost if you look at the examples below. That is exactly why I didn't add handlebars to the question. Because it causes confusion and it's not relevant to what I want to do.

Comment: what is you question now? about sorting or moving the sorted result to screen?

Comment: @NinaScholz sorting the output html. It's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all you need to do, is call **append** on the html elements in the sort order.

This will append the element in the end of the html elements.

```
var sortHTML = function(locations) {
  $.each(locations, function(i, location) {
    var targetElement = $('#' + location.store.id);
    targetElement.parent().append(targetElement)
  });
};
sortHTML(locations);
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wbcj026x/1/

Comment: That is actually more like what I'm looking for. But there is no way to just sort? I'm thinking if this could be a performance issue.

Comment: how is this different from my answer?, it uses the same append function

Comment: @Dejan.S, The answer is no, there is no way to move html elements in the DOM rather then append/detach (adding/removing element from the DOM)

Comment: @madalinivascu, The difference is that you did it on execution-time and my  function can be used after execution-time.